# Microsoft Event hub send java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, azure

I am following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-send) on Microsoft website to get a simple send event to Azure event hub to work in java. However, I used maven and followed every thing but the final jar file runs with exception errors. Please here is what I did.

I created simple Maven project in Eclipse Juno and here is the content of my pom.xml

```
`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <description>Java libraries for talking to Windows Azure Event Hubs</description>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
<artifactId>send</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
       <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.2</version>
       <configuration>
         <archive>
           <manifest>
             <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
             <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
             <mainClass>com.bd.Send</mainClass>
           </manifest>
         </archive>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
 </build>

 <dependencies>
        <dependency> 
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId> 
        <artifactId>azure-eventhubs</artifactId> 
        <version>0.14.0</version> 
        </dependency>   
 </dependencies>


 </project>`
```

Is this pom.xml file correct? as when I run the final jar file, i get exception errors but the project compiles correctly.

How can I configure the send event hub java project using maven ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think your `pom.xml` file is correct. Please post the exception error information you got at there. It can help analyzing your issue and find out the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My problem was that I didn't include all the jar dependencies in final build. I will post the answer.

Comment: OK, I see. It sounds like you forgot to extract or package required libraries into your generated JAR.

Answer (score 1):

This is the pom.xml file that worked:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>send</groupId>
  <artifactId>send</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>osssonatype</id>
        <name>OSS Sonatype</name>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>



  <dependencies>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId> 
        <artifactId>azure-eventhubs</artifactId> 
        <version>0.14.0</version> 
    </dependency>   

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- any other plugins -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>sdasf.Send</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

When Run as Maven install. Inside the target folder there will be 2 jar files. Running the one with dependencies solved my issue.

on the cmd command line:

```
java -jar send-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```